# Why does my Java program shut down without any error messages under heavy load?

Tags: java, crash

My Java program crashes (in Eclipse) when I load in a fairly large file.

I have run VisualVM and my CPU seems to peak at 20% usage before crashing and my heap size doesn't seem too high. The number of threads running at the time of crash is ~20.

I do receive error messages - but not every time the crash occurs. The two error messages I receive are:

> [Too many errors, abort]

and

> # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>
> #
>
> #  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f096d096942, pid=12102, tid=139678234564352
>
> #
>
> # JRE version: 6.0_24-b24
>
> # Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (20.0-b12 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
>
> # Derivative: IcedTea6 1.11.5
>
> # Distribution: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, package 6b24-1.11.5-0ubuntu1~12.04.1
>
> # Problematic frame:
>
> # J  java.util.HashMap.put(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;

I have found a thread pertaining to the second warning, but it seems to suggest a hardware issue. I believe my error is in the software since it only seems to happen in specific instances of larger input files.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems likely it's an `OutOfMemoryException`, although I admit Eclipse usually reports these.

However note that the heap size for launched apps is *different* from the heap size for the IDE itself, and the default is quite small (can't remember, but it ain't big).

Look at VM settings for your default launch profile, or change the VM for the app specific launch to add lots of heap with `-Xmx1G` or whatever

Comment: I believe this was the problem. Thanks to both of you (chubbsondubs) - I'm awarding it to you because you were faster by a minute. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The JVM will crash if it's been given permission to use X amount of memory, but the system doesn't have any more memory to give it.  For example, you have said it can use 512MB (-Xmx512m), and your program's heap is using only 128MB.  It should be allowed to allocate another 384MB.  However, when it goes to allocate some more memory the machine is tapped, and the OS says no, JVM will crash in these situations.  Looking at CPU usage, and heap size look normal, but the the problem is the machine doesn't have any more memory to give it.  So check your total memory and free memory when this happens and see if you are just running out of memory.

Interestingly if you lower your upper memory (-Xmx) on the JVM it might keep it from crashing because it will force Java to GC before allocating more memory.  But lower it too far and it will run slow or just throw a OOM exception.  This is why it's important to pick a size that isn't too big or too small for your app to run effectively.  You could also look to allocate more up front, or change your program so it uses memory more efficiently.  You'll want to shutdown processes that are eating up your memory that aren't central to your app or just buy more memory.